# Javascript append data every 2 seconds to Apexchart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am trying to create a chart in Apexchart that, when a button is clicked, will add a new data every 2 seconds  5 times. My code is as follows:

```js
var salesdata=[30,40,45,50,49,60,70,91,125];
var buysdata=[20,30,45,52,42,33,40,41,65];
var i=0;
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: salesdata,
  },
          {
    name: 'buys',
    data: buysdata,
  }],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005]
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
 

function update(){

  function appendStats(){
    i++;
   

   salesdata.push(salesdata[salesdata.length-1]+22);
   buysdata.push(buysdata[buysdata.length-1]+32);
   chart.appendData([{
     data: 0,
     }])
  if(i===4)
    clearInterval(timerId);
 }


   let timerId=setInterval(appendStats,2000); 
 
 }
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 35px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<button onclick='update()'>Click me</button>
<div id="chart">
</div>
```

The problem is that instead of updating one data, waiting for 2 seconds and appending another data. The code waits for 10 seconds and appends the data in one go. How do I fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**: Updated the code and it works fine now. **setInterval** did the trick.

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run something periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Your sleep function can be rewritten to

```js
function recSleep(timesToRepeat, timeMS) {
  appendStats(); 
  if (timesToRepeat > 1) {
    setTimeout(() => {
       recSleep(timesToRepeat - 1, timeMS)
    }, timeMS);
  }
}
```

Then in your `update` function call it like `recSleep(5, 2000)`